# In which cases can an SSL server omit sending the certificate?

Tags: ssl, certificate

I'm trying to figure out the SSL handshake process. After reading up on [TLS in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security) I've seen that

> The server sends its Certificate message (depending on the selected cipher suite, this may be omitted by the server)

I've also seen such behavior in real-life sniffs, but only in cases where the user eventually received an "Invalid certificate" warning.

I was wondering in which cases can a server omit the certificate? How can the client verify the server's identity in this case then? Or is it only reserved to cases where the server have no certificate and gives up on sending a fake one, knowing that the user will see a browser warning anyway?

Thanks!

Comment: For the same reason [this question](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/9500/2435) was closed (i.e. not a programming question), this could also be moved to Security.SE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some cipher suites don't rely on certificates:

- The [anonymous cipher suites](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-7.4.2), defined in the main TLS RFC (the names containing `DH_anon`). Some of them can provide encryption, but without authentication, which is insecure. [Section A.5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#appendix-A.5) says the following about them:

> The following cipher suites are used for completely anonymous
> Diffie-Hellman communications in which neither party is
> authenticated.  Note that this mode is vulnerable to man-in-the-
> middle attacks.  Using this mode therefore is of limited use: These
> cipher suites MUST NOT be used by TLS 1.2 implementations unless the
> application layer has specifically requested to allow anonymous key
> exchange.  (Anonymous key exchange may sometimes be acceptable, for
> example, to support opportunistic encryption when no set-up for
> authentication is in place, or when TLS is used as part of more
> complex security protocols that have other means to ensure
> authentication.)

- [Kerberos cipher suites](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2712), in which case the identification is done via the Kerberos ticket, and the name is verified against the Kerberos principal name (`host/MachineName@Realm`).
- [Pre-Shared Keys cipher suites](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4279) (see section on *PSK Identity Encoding*).

Answer (score 0):

There is one valid case for anonymous ciphers: the opportunistic encryption of e-mail over SMTP with STARTTLS. As an MITM could easily prevent the use of TLS, there is no use in protecting agains MITM at the TLS level.

If the client knows that he will proceed anyway, even if the certificate was invalid, the can request an anonymous ciphersuite saving the server the generation of a signature and himself the verification the certificate and the signature.